# Maximum update depth exceeded when trying to redirect page based on localStorage condition

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I have React app and I have a user in local storage.

In many cases, I need to check if there is a user, so I pulled it into a utility file and exported:

`export const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));`

Then I import and use in the components I need, for example:

```
import { user } from '../../utils';

const Dashboard = () => {

  if (!user) return <Redirect to='/auth' />;
  return <h1>Dashboard</h1>;
};
```

But this error happens to me:

```
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

however, when I access the localstorage in the component itself I don't get an error.

```
const Dashboard = () => {
 
  const user = localStorage.getItem('user');

  if (!user) return <Redirect to='/auth' />;
  return <h1>Dashboard</h1>;
};
```

Is there any better way I can utilize
that or do I have to use it this way in each component?

Comment: You should really use an `useEffect` to do any side-effects, like reading from localStorage. Use an empty dependency array if you want the effect to run once on mount. Since it looks like you are using `react-router-dom` then you may want to consider abstracting the `user` logic into a custom route component to handle the redirect. Review the [auth workflow demo](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) for the general idea.

Comment: I will definitely use the protected route approach

Comment: If you run into or have any further issues implementing those changes then either update your question here if there are no further answers, or post a new question with the relevant code and issue details. Feel free to ping (@) me in a comment and I can see if I can help. Cheers.